auto-complete with `pass` on mac
I am used to have auto-complete with pass (https://www.passwordstore.org/) out of the box in the standard terminal of Ubuntu. However, on my mac running macOS 14.6.1 (Sonoma) there is no auto-complete. This makes the usage of pass really inconvenient.
I have seen this post, where additional software is installed, but it still fails. One answer suggest that only one path is not set exactly, but this didn't do the job for me.
So my question is: What is the most elementary way to get auto-completion for pass on a mac?
Apparently, pass provides an extra auto-completion for zsh pass auto-completion files as pointed out in one comment under this answer. However, I don't know how I can tell zsh to use it.
edits according to comments
output of echo $SHELL: /bin/zsh

Shells, including zsh, have lots of different ways they can be told to source shell scripts that add functionality. The details of how best to tell your own preferred shell environment to source a pass auto-completion file depends on the shell you're using and how you've already customized its startup environment. For starters, can you edit your question to include the output of echo $SHELL from your usual shell environment? That will help us confirm whether you're starting from macOS's built-in zsh setup, or the Homebrew system's zsh setup, or what.

@Spiff I have updated the response of the terminal.

@Spiff so the output tells me I am in the macOS setup and apparently since I installed pass with brew in have to be in brew setup, right? How do I switch?

Run brew install zsh and follow Homebrew's instructions for switching your shell to the Homebrew-installed copy of zsh. I'm not sure how much of the process brew automates for that, but in general, switching to a new shell means adding the path to the new shell to /etc/shells and then doing chsh -s /path/to/new/shell.

@Spiff I did that and now I get /opt/homebrew/bin/zsh as output of echo $SHELL, but autocomplete is still not working for pass

I finally managed to make it work. However, I am not sure whether all steps are really necessary.
I think the only thing one really has to do is install zsh-completions by brew install zsh-completions and follow the instructions that are prompted after the installation is finished.
However, maybe it is important to also install zsh from brew what Spiff suggested in the comments to the question. Since I did this before I cannot say whether it was a necessary step.
Unfortunately, this is not as elementary as I hoped, because I need an additional program instead of tell zsh that the auto-completion file for pass is located at /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_pass, but maybe there is a fundamental misunderstanding.
